# Curl is not being recognized

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have literally tried all methods possible on StackOverflow. My PHP is not recognizing curl. I created a phpinfo.php file to provide me with the configuration.

I have tried:

- uncommenting extension=php_curl.dll (I even tried changing the name to extension=C:\amp\PHP\ext\php_curl.dll)
- Moving my  libeay32.dll libssh2.dll and ssleay32.dll into apache/bin and even tried moving those files in the C:\Windows\System32 folder
- I created a file path in the Environment variables for the PHP and apache folder

Nothing has worked for me so far!

Comment: I tend to recommend WAMP or XAMPP if you're not well versed in configuring PHP and Apache yourself.   Did you restart Apache after updating php.ini?  (Assuming php is running under mod_php).

Comment: How are you trying to use `cURL`? If from the command line, are you modifying the correct php.ini file? Same goes for running it via a browser. Does your `phpinfo()` show `cURL` installed and enabled?

Comment: @Devon It worked WAMP!